# PHP Excel library Spout on windows server

Tags: php, import-from-excel

I'am trying to start with a excel library named "Spout": https://github.com/box/spout

If I set everything as described in the documentation, so it throws this error:

```
XMLReader::open(zip://D:/wamp/www/lumidee/user_uploads/xls_import/create/katalog-lucis.xlsx#/xl/worksheets/sheet1.xml): failed to open stream: operation failed
```

On unix server fedora with the same settings it goes without problem, but on windows wamp server is problem.

You do not know what's the problem?
Does anybody have a solution?

Thank you.

Comment: Hey @kevas, the issue was fixed as part of v1.0.2 (see https://github.com/box/spout/releases).